# How to efficiently subset from a cell pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following problem:
In a column `agent_string` is a long string like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36
```

I need to create a new column `typ_browser` where will be the last word of `agent_string` or "Chrome" if the word "Chrome" is in `agent_string`. I came up with this solution, which is unfortunately very slow, because I have 500.000 rows:

```
data["typ_browser"] = ""

def zjisti_browser(agent):
    rozdeleno = agent.split(" ")
    if "Chrome" in agent:
        return "Chrome"
    return rozdeleno[-1]

for i in range(len(data["agent_string"])):
    data["typ_browser"][i] = zjisti_browser(data["agent_string"][i])
```

Is there something faster?

Comment: you can use `apply()`. `df['browser_type'] = df['agent_string'].apply(lambda x: 'Chrome' if 'Chrome' in x else x.split(' ')[-1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with test values by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), if no match get last value after `split`:

```
data["typ_browser"] = np.where(data["agent_string"].str.contains('Chrome'), 
                               'Chrome',
                               data["agent_string"].str.split().str[-1])
```

Or:

```
data["typ_browser"] = np.where(data["agent_string"].str.contains('Chrome'), 
                               'Chrome',
                               data["agent_string"].str.extract(r'(\S*$)', expand=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the values from one column (Series) to create another, you can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with your function to create the new column.

```
data["typ_browser"] = data["agent_string"].map(zjisti_browser)
```

This will apply the function `zjisti_browser` to each element in your `agent_string` and return a new column.

---

Also, note how [jezrael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507593/1288) avoids splitting the string if it doesn't need to. You can do that in your function too.

```
def zjisti_browser(agent):
    if "Chrome" in agent:
        return "Chrome"
    return agent.split()[-1]
```

This will be a small performance improvement no matter which solution you choose.

Comment: Thanks, is it faster than loop?

Comment: @vojtam Yes, it should be. Looping over the rows of a dataframe is usually not recommended because it's slow.